# Snort command run through python script

Tags: python, scripting, command, snort

I am trying to read the snort alert in the console for one of my project.

What I did is, I wrote a following code to run the snort to listen to my interface.

```
import subprocess

command = 'snort -l /var/log/snort  -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -A console -i s1-eth1'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

I run the above script through another python script as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

script_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd() +'/', 'comm.py')
p = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', script_path],
      stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)
with p.stdout:
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
p.wait()
```

The output of the script takes me where snort listens. but when doing experiment that triggers the rule of snort file to alert, its not printing the output in terminal where i ran the python script.

when I run the snort command in the normal terminal the alert message prints all fine.

does any know any work around for this.

Thanks in advance.